# List of Author/editor's id's in mediawiki skin

Tags: php, mediawiki

I am writing a hack for a mediawiki skin that displays photos of all of the users that have edited the page (including the author).

I have already *(successfully) written an extension that allows users to upload a photo of themselves. The images are stored in the /images/ directory with the user_id as the name.

So my question is how do I extract a list of editors user ID's from the page itself?

I assume its something like this:

```
<?php foreach($this->data['revisions_user_id'] as $editorID) ?>
```

But I don't think 'revisions_user_id' is the right element does anyone know the right one?

Comment: lol I figured it out. Just in case anyone is looking for a similar solution.
The answer was to use an SQL query to get the user info from the 'revisions' table. Like this:

    $dbr = wfGetDB( DB_SLAVE );
    $res = $dbr->select ('revision', array('DISTINCT rev_user', 'rev_user_text'), 'rev_page="' . $this->data['articleid'] . '"', 'GROUP BY rev_user');

wfGetDB() is the mediawiki Database interface (FYI).

Comment: You should add an answer and mark it as the correct one. Good job tracking this down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use an SQL query to get the user info from the 'revisions' table. Like this:

```
$dbr = wfGetDB( DB_SLAVE ); 
$res = $dbr->select ('revision', array('DISTINCT rev_user', 'rev_user_text'), 'rev_page="' . $this->data['articleid'] . '"', 'GROUP BY rev_user');
```

wfGetDB() is the mediawiki Database interface (FYI).